# How to send an SMS longer than 160 words without split up?

Tags: android

I'm sending on my Android App an SMS longer than 160 characters. Is there some example code to do that without splitting up the message? I need the sms to arrive as one long sms.

Comment: You send an MMS instead.  SMS is limited to 160 7 bit characters at max.  But most phones will display a MMS as an SMS

Comment: On the other hand, MMSs cost much more than regular SMSs. I suggest you using eMails or Telegram. Or WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in short, impossible. **Why?** This is the global standard of the GSM which was created when the first phone was created. It is not within the power of the app to decide what limit of characters there can be in an SMS.

The character limit was already set ***decades*** ago...

Here is a brief piece on the reason why the SMS character limit is  160-140 characters....

> So back in 1985 there was this guy named Friedhelm Hillebrand, who was
>   the chairman of the non-voice services committee within the Global
>   System for Mobile Communications (GSM), a group that sets standards
>   for the majority of the global mobile market. This guy had the task of
>   setting the limit on the amount of characters a text message could
>   contain.
>
> To do this, Friedhelm sat at his typewriter, typing out random
>   sentences and questions on a sheet of paper to see what the average
>   amount of characters he used was. He found that each set of sentences,
>   ran just under 160 characters in length. That was good enough for him,
>   so he told his committee that text messages would be limited to 160
>   characters. Pretty scientific right?
>
> Friedhelm’s methods didn’t sit well with the rest of the committee, as
>   they doubted a text message limited to 160 characters would be enough
>   space to prove a useful form of communication. So to calm their fears,
>   he backed up his assumption of limiting text messages to 160
>   characters by doing the following “market research”.
>
> 1. Friedhelm took a bunch of postcards that he had received and found that often these postcards contained fewer than 150 characters. By
>      this finding, he was being nice by offering consumers an additional 10
>      characters.
> 2. Friedhelm then analyzed a bunch of messages sent through Telex (a telegraphy network for business professionals). Even though these
>      Telex transmissions didn’t have a limit on the amount of characters
>      they were able to send, he found that on average the Telex messages
>      were about the same length as the postcards.
>
> So that’s why text messages are limited to 160 characters.

Hope this is enlightening.